# Encryption Crypt - Trying to get to work in PHP same way as Perl

Tags: php, perl, encryption

I have written encryption functionality in Perl and I am trying to get to work same way in PHP.

In PERL:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Crypt::CBC;
use Crypt::Rijndael;

my $cryptkey = '_PRIVATE_';

my $cipher = Crypt::CBC->new( -key    => $cryptkey,
                              -salt   => 1,
                              -cipher => 'Rijndael',
                             );

my $data = "hello";

my $ciphertext = $cipher->encrypt_hex($data);

print "HEX_KEY: '$ciphertext' \n";
```

**Output:**

> HEX_KEY: '53616c7465645f5fc36630f5364619c31ac26e44809c81bf84ae995c22be45ce'

I am trying to get to work in PHP and output same HEX but it is not the same, what went wrong?

```
class Test {

    public function Encypt($data, $cryptkey) {

        $encrypted = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $cryptkey, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);

        return bin2hex($encrypted);
    }
}


$data = "hello";

$test = new Test();

$cryptkey = "_PRIVATE_";

$hex =  $test->Encypt($data, $cryptkey);
echo $hex;
```

**Output**

> 2bab1b8874692176d213e4c23565b304

Comment: This is *not* the core of your problem, but notice that your `$data` in Perl has an extra newline at the end of the string, whereas in the PHP code you do not have such a newline – construct the input the same way in both test cases to avoid such issues.

Comment: @amon Thanks for pointing it out, I have changed `$data` without newlines.. It still doesn't match up same HEX.

Answer (score 3):

`Crypt::CBC` and `mcrypt_encrypt` use different defaults, which lead to this mismatch.

For [`mcrypt_encrypt`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php), the documentation offers this information:

> `string mcrypt_encrypt ( string $cipher , string $key , string $data , string $mode [, string $iv ] )`
>
> - `$cipher` is the algorithm name.
> - `$key` is the encryption key, if it is too short it will be padded with NUL bytes.
> - `$data` is the data to be encrypted, if it is too short it will be padded with NUL bytes.
> - `$mode` is the mode of operation, here `"cbc"` is correct.
> - `$iv` is the initialization vector, if not provided it will be initialized as NUL bytes.

For [`Crypt::CBC`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Crypt%3a%3aCBC), we get this behaviour instead:

> `Crypt::CBC->new(KEYWORD_OPTIONS)`
>
> - `-key => STRING` is the passphrase from which the encryption key is generated by some hashing operations.
> - `-literal_key => BOOL` If set, this skips the hashing for the `-key` and uses it as a literal key.
> - `-cipher => CIPHER` the name of a cipher, or a pre-initialized cipher object.
> - `-salt => 1 | STRING` If set to `"1"`, this will produce a random salt. Any other values are taken as the literal salt. This defaults to `-salt => 1` if a salt is needed. Or something like that, the docs are a bit confusing here. The salt is not needed if both the `-iv` and `literal_key` options are set.
> - `-iv => STRING` is the initialization vector, which is usually generated from the salt.
> - `-header => STRING` controls what kind of header is prepended to the output. This defaults to `"salt"`, but can also be set to `"none"`.

Note further that `RIJNDAEL_128` implies a keylength of 16, whereas `Crypt::CBC` assumes a keylength of `32`.

Using [`Crypt::Rijndael`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Crypt%3a%3aRijndael) without the `Crypt::CBC` wrapper is probably preferable, because this allows us to easily set the required options to the same defaults which PHP uses:

```
use Crypt::Rijndael;

my $key = "_PRIVATE_";
my $data = "hello";

# pad the $key to 16 bytes
$key .= "\0" x (16 - length $key);
# pad the $data to a multiple of 16 bytes:
if (my $distance = length($data) % 16) {
    $data .= "\0" x (16 - $distance);
}

my $crypt = Crypt::Rijndael->new($key, Crypt::Rijndael::MODE_CBC);
$crypt->set_iv("\0" x 16);

my $binary = $crypt->encrypt($data);
print unpack("H*", $binary), "\n";
```

Which then outputs `2bab1b8874692176d213e4c23565b304`.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Is there any chance you can do it other way round? in PHP make RIJNDAEL apply keylength of 32 somehow.

Comment: @user1246800 Use the `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256` algorithm instead of `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128` to use the 32-byte key length in PHP. However, that does not resolve the other differences: You will have to manually pad the key for `Crypt::CBC`, specify `-literal_key`, and provide an explicit `-iv`.