# Mcrypt perl and PHP function

Tags: perl, encryption, cryptography, mcrypt, blowfish

I have Encrypt and Decrypt functions in PHP

```php
function Encrypt($plaintext, $key = "12345678901234")
{
    $cipher = MCRYPT_BLOWFISH;
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size($cipher, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);

    $key = pack('H*', $key);
    $ciphertext = mcrypt_encrypt($cipher, $key, $plaintext, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
    $ciphertext = $iv . $ciphertext;
    $ciphertext = bin2hex($ciphertext);

    return $ciphertext;
}


function Decrypt($strBase64CipherText, $key = "12345678901234")
{
    $cipher = MCRYPT_BLOWFISH;

    $ciphertext_dec = hex2bin($strBase64CipherText);

    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size($cipher, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);

    $iv = substr($ciphertext_dec, 0, $iv_size);
    $ciphertext = substr($ciphertext_dec, $iv_size);

    $key = pack('H*', $key);

    $plaintext =  mcrypt_decrypt($cipher, $key, $ciphertext, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
    $plaintext =  rtrim($plaintext, chr(0));

    return $plaintext;
}
```

This functions works well.

Now I need the same Encrypt function in Perl. My problem is that the encrypted text in Perl cannot decrypted in PHP.

I tried whith static $iv. I try with Mcrypt, Crypt::CBC
Now my code shows like this

```perl
sub EncryptSalt {($params) = @_;

    my $key = '12345678901234';
    $key = pack('H*', $key);

    my $iv = '12345678';

    my($cipher) = Mcrypt->new
    (
        algorithm => Mcrypt::BLOWFISH,
        mode => Mcrypt::CBC
    );
    $cipher->init($key, $iv);

    my $ciphertext = $cipher->encrypt($params);

    $ciphertext = $iv . $ciphertext;
    $ciphertext = unpack('H*', $ciphertext);

    return $ciphertext;
}
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22449991/1331451